# How to draw a graph in asp.net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to represent a Graphical analysis in a web application which is being developed in .net 2.0. 
I refereed some of the jquery plugin but did not find appropriate.

I want to present a graph similar to reputation section of stack overflow if you've seen.
Please help to find such a graph plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can find a lot of jquery graph

[1. jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

[2. Jquery Visualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_visualize_plugin_accessible_charts_graphs_from_tables_html5_canvas/)

[3. HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

[4. Jquery Sparklines](http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)

[5. Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

Personally, I work with `jqplot` and ASP.NET MVC3 and `jqplot` makes great job.

For .net 2.0 you may access the following links:

http://www.nilzorblog.com/2010/01/using-microsoft-chart-controls-in-net.html

http://www.chartingcontrol.net/

[Read MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/31b16ff8-f61f-457d-ad45-4f557cdb1381/)

http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, it's very useful and maybe can help you:

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are at least from what I am thinking 4 ways to make graphs.

1. Using **pure css** and divs
2. Using **javascript** that build the graph
3. Using **Flash**, or **Silverlight**
4. Using the code behind to **draw the graph** on an image.

From all that you ask for the one that looks like the SO, so that **is the css way**.

Look some example and code on that pages:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/data-visualization-with-css-graphs-charts-and-more/
http://acrisdesign.com/2009/09/20-tutorials-on-css-graph-and-charts/
http://designmodo.com/css-graph-chart-tutorials/

but also you can search for the "making graph using css"

Actually what you do here, you use Div that you formatted with css that makes them look likes bars. Then on code behind you only need to give the correct parameters when you render this graph.

In generally there are too many examples on each field, many ready to use code or libraries, so I focus on the one you ask for, the css way.